# Como posso obter o input do html para o js

Tags: javascript, html

Como é que eu posso pegar no input de alguem no html e dar log (`console.log`) na consola.
Basicamente eu quero poder pegar no `input` do utilizador e dar log dele na consola (`console.log`)
Porfavor caso ache que a pergunta esta mal estruturada explique no que posso melhorar e não dê logo -1!

**FORM HTML**

```
<form id="OrderForm">
            <input id="ON" class="OrderName" type="text" name="OrderName" placeholder="Buyer Name" value="" required>
            <input id="OD" class="OrderDate" type="text" name="OrderDate" placeholder="Date of Order" required>
            <input id="sku" class="SKU" type="text" name="ProductSKU" placeholder="Product SKU" required>
            <input class="SUBMIT" type="submit" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT">
          </form>
```

**WEBSITE**

```js
function appendOrders(orders) {
  var ElementOrders = document.getElementById("Orders")
  ElementOrders.innerHTML = orders
}

function appendEarnings(earnings) {
  var ElementEarnings = document.getElementById("Earnings");
  ElementEarnings.innerHTML = earnings
}

function JSONLOAD() {
  "use strict";

  fetch("Static/Data/DATA.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      var Earnings = data.DataInfo[0].Earnings;
      appendEarnings(Earnings);
      var Orders = data.DataInfo[0].Orders;
      appendOrders(Orders)
    })
}

JSONLOAD()
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #252C35;
  color: white;
}

#UpperBar {
  height: 45px;
}

.MASlime {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 40px;
}

#Totals {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.Total {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 130px;
}

.TotalEarnings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 200px;
}

.TotalO {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 130px;
}

.TotalOrders {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 200px;
}

#Earnings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 350px;
}

#Orders {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 350px;
}

.NewOrder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.OrderName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.OrderDate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.SKU {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.SUBMIT {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 220px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 480px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAED;
  border-top: 1px solid #EAEAED;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #252C35;
}

.All {
  display: block;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadein 1.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity: 0.3; }
  50% { opacity: 0.5; }
  75% { opacity: 0.8; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EComerce App Slime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Static/css/index.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="Static/Images/favicon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <label for="toggle" class="Menu">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="meuMenuToggle()"/>
      <div class="menu">
          <a href="#">Slime Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="UpperBar">
      <p class="MASlime">MASlime</p>
    </div>
      <div id="HomePage">
        <div id="Totals">
          <p class="Total">Total</p>
          <p class="TotalEarnings">Earnings</p>
          <p class="TotalO">Total</p>
          <p class="TotalOrders">Orders</p>
          <p id="Earnings">100€</p>
          <p id="Orders">1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="NewOrder">
          <p class="NewOrder">New Order</p>
          <form id="OrderForm">
            <input id="ON" class="OrderName" type="text" name="OrderName" placeholder="Buyer Name" value="" required>
            <input class="OrderDate" type="text" name="OrderDate" placeholder="Date of Order" required>
            <input class="SKU" type="text" name="ProductSKU" placeholder="Product SKU" required>
            <input class="SUBMIT" type="submit" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT">
          </form>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          input = document.getElementById("ON")
          console.log(input.value)
          </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var home = document.getElementById('HomePage');
    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];
    menu.style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = () => {

    if (menu.style.display == 'none') setTimeout(fadeMenu, 150);
    else if(menu.style.display == 'block') setTimeout(fadeHome, 150);
    }

    function fadeMenu() {
      home.style.display = 'none';
      menu.classList.add('fadeIn');
      menu.style.display =  'block';
    }

    function fadeHome() {
      home.style.display = 'block';
      home.classList.add('fadeIn');
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    <script src="Static/js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer dar um `console.log()` no que o user escreveu no `input`, você pode pegar a tag pelo *id* e assim, conseguir o valor dela.

```
input = document.getElementById("ON")
console.log(input.value)
```

Se você quiser que ele seja printado no console quando o user clicar no botão de submit, você pode adicionar um `eventListener` no Form.

```
<form onsubmit="printInput()">
  <input type="text" id="ON">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
  function printInput(){
    input = document.getElementById("ON");
    console.log(input.value);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Isto é a unica coisa que ele está a dizer na consola `?OrderName=Antonio&OrderDate=1%2F11%2F1&ProductSKU=198&Submit=SUBMIT:39` e neste caso o que eu queria apenas o Antonio do nome!

Comment: Sim, isso acontece quando você clica no submit, os valores do input são passados na URL. Se você quiser o valor do input quando o usuário clicar, você colocar um eventListener na sua form pra quando o user clicar, ele printar no console de javascript o valor.

Comment: Poderia porfavor explicar como eu posso fazer isso !

Comment: Editei minha resposta!